# ajax image if port open, alternate image if not open

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

So I'm trying to create a custom script for a website of mine, and I'm looking at doing a status script. now I've done some research however I have scrapped what I have until I can find something that works better.

I am currently using fopen to check if a port is open, however it slows the page load time down considerably, I was wondering if there is a way to do this is jquery and ajax. allow the page to load first, then present an image if the port was open, and an alternate image if it was closed or inaccessible.

I've seen it done before, I just can't seem to find any documentation on this.

Comment: Please add your problematic code to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Load the page, send an ajax request to your page to check if it's open or not.

```
$.getJSON('checkstatus.php', {
    port: 8070
}, function (data) {
    if (data.status === 'on') {
        $('#img').attr('src', 'on.png');
    } else {
        $('#img').attr('src', 'off.png');
    }
});

<?php
......code.....

header('content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('status'=>get_port_status($_GET['port'])));
```

edit :

```
//checkstatus.php
<?php
$host = $_GET['host'];
$ports = array(PORT 1, PORT 2, PORT 3, PORT 4, PORT 5, PORT 6, PORT 7, PORT 8, PORT 9);
$status = array();
foreach($ports as $port) {
    $connection = @fsockopen($host, $port);
    if (is_resource($connection)) {
        $[$port] = 'on';
        fclose($connection);
    } else {
        $[$port] = 'off';
    }
}

header('content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($status);
?>

///status.html
<table id="portStatus">
   <tbody></tbody>
</table>

<script>
$(function () {
    var table = $('#portStatus tbody');
    var hosts = ['host1.com', 'host2.com'];
    for (var i = 0; i < hosts.length; ++i) {
        var host = hosts[i];
        $.getJSON('checkstatus.php', {
            host: host
        }, function (data) {
            var tr = $('<tr/>');
            tr.append($('td').html(host)); //this appends the hostname to the td;
            for (var port in data) {
                tr.append($('<td><img src="' + (data[port] === 'on' ? 'accept.png' : 'error.png') + '"></td>');
                }
                table.append(tr);
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

This should give you a basic idea, try it and modify it.
Note, the javascript part uses jQuery.

Comment: what if the ports are dynamic, meaning specified in another code, how I would reflect that in fpassthru(fopen(is_open ? 'on.png' : 'off.png', 'rb'));

Comment: No reason to make PHP serve the image, more load. Better to have an AJAX call to a script to check if the port is open. If so, then display the image. Your way will also not reduce the time the browser thinks the page is "loading".

Comment: My current code is:

$host = 'server.url';
$ports = array(XX, XX, XX, XX, XX, XX); ?>

Comment: ok you need to show more code in your original post or paste it somewhere.

Comment: sorry. here is the link to the entire code i use now.
http://pastebin.com/ssAZSGh1

Comment: You will have to separate the php and and html then do something similar to what I showed you.

Comment: is there an easier way to accomplish the same task? for example pass a variable to the "checkstatus.php" page and get the same result? The code I created from scratch not knowing what I was doing.

Comment: thank you very much, i can use this and make it my own. I appreciate everyone's help!

Comment: You're welcome, if it helped, select it as the right answer :)